# What happened to some directories in retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

In retrofit 1.9.0, there were these directories and some classes in them:

[image]

And now in retrofit 2.2.0, there is only 'http'. No 'mime', 'converter', etc.

Am I doing something wrong or are they just restructured or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `retrofit 2` they changed project structure. So now convertes and other components are provided as separate modules.

Here is a link for migration : [upgrade guide from 1.9](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-upgrade-guide-from-1-9)

Also read this : [The biggest update yet on the best HTTP Client Library for Android](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en)